# What does my solution probability represent?

Tags: probability

Suppose three balls are chosen at random (without replacement) from a bag. The bag consist of 4 white balls and 5 blue balls.
let W denote number of white balls

Calculate $P(W \geq 1) $

I'm having difficulty understanding why my methodology was incorrect. What does my solution probability represent?

How I did it:

```
(W, B, B) - 3 Sample Points
(W, W, B) - 3 Sample Points
(W, W, W) - 1 Sample Point
```

$ 7/(_3^9) = \frac{7}{84}$

However the solution is 
$$P(W \geq 1) = 1 - P(W=0)$$
$$1 - (_3^5)/(_3^9) = \frac{74}{84} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (W, B, B) - 3 Sample Points 
>   (W, W, B) - 3 Sample Points 
>   (W, W, W) - 1 Sample Point

You've got that the balls can be selected in any order, but neglected that there are 4 white balls and 5 blue balls.   Just as ways to select any 3 from 9 balls is counted by $\binom 93$, then

(W, B, B) - $\binom 4 1\binom 5 2$  Sample Points 
 (W, W, B) - $\binom 4 2\binom 5 1$ Sample Points 
 (W, W, W) - $\binom 4 3\binom 5 0$ Sample Point

But it is more compact to use the complement , as: $~\mathsf P(W\geq 1)=1-\mathsf P(W=0)$  $$\dfrac{\dbinom 9 3 - \color{silver}{\dbinom 4 0}\dbinom 5 3}{\dbinom 9 4}$$

Answer (score 1):

One of the mistakes is that you did not consider $W=1$ but only consider $W \geq 2$.

What about $(W,B,W)$?

I also can't see how you obtain $3$ sample points for $(B,W,W)$.

Edit:

I see that you are counting how many configurations are there. This is not sufficient. You did not consider  total number of white and blue balls are there initially in your computations.

Comment: I apologize, there was a typo, I fixed it now.
and to the second question: (B,W,W), (W,B,W),(B,W,W)

Comment: @user Keep in mind that there are 5 distinct blue balls, and 4 distinct white balls.